# How to display an image using kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How do I display an image in my pwd?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Image('b1.png')

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check the [Image documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html) to see that the image source is controlled by the `source` property. Therefore you should be able to change just one line to make it work:

```
    return Image(source='b1.png')
```

Answer (score 4):

The acceptable result for me is too comprehensive and simple.

**I have a better way of doing it using .kv file:**

- Set your photo at a particular box_layout using "ids"
- You can change your photo dynamically

Kivy.kv (file)

```
<main_display>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        
        Image:
              id: imageView
              source: '<random_name>.jpg'
              allow_stretch: True
 ....
```

Kivy.py (file)

```
class main_display(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(main_display,self).__init__()
       # Photo can be reference by running the photo function once:
       Clock.schedule_once(self.photo)
    
     def photo(self,dt):
       # Replace the given image source value:
       self.ids.imageView.source = 'kivy_test.jpg'
```

1. Basically, set your image file name under source attribute under
   "Image" in kivy.kv (file).
2. Remember to set a clock schedule once as above and you can make your modification of your photo. You can even add some photo looping (dynamically) by changing the clock scheduler to `Clock.schedule_interval(self.photo, 0.06)`.

*I have try to directly assign the
attribute 'source' from kivy.py (file) but failed with assertion
error.*

ENJOY and please do comment if you're not clear !